# How to get coordinates of a set of points on the sides of equilateral triangle in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

[image: points on the triangle]

I have an equilateral triangle. I know coordinates of the center (S), all vertices (A, B, C) and the length of the circle radius (r). How can I get the coordinates of variable amount of points [X1, X2, X3, ...] located on sides (a) of the triangle distributed uniformly (eg. with the same distance from each other)? Is there some formula?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. _"coordinates of any point"_ - meaning, _all_ of them? _All_ possible ones? That would be an _indefinite_ number ...

Comment: It depends on how these points are defined

Comment: To be more clear I need exact amount of that points (eg. 8). That points have to be evenly distributed around the triangle.

Comment: Still not clear, after been more clear.   Currently not even sure what has the circle got to do with anything?.  `(eg. 8)`, what you mean 4 * 2.   `evenly distributed`, but your image doesn't show that..  Confused..!!! (brain hurts now).. :)

Comment: Edited the question. Is that more clear?

Comment: Take a smaller circle and calculate the points where it collides with the triangle to get the points using a circle formula and 3 lines fomulas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224912/circle-line-segment-collision

Comment: You mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041729/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-6-point-of-intersection-between-a-circle-and-a-e But what about the case I need any amount of points as the variable input?

Comment: I found the way how to show what I need :) Replaced image in the question...

Comment: If you have the equations of two straight lines (in 2D) that are not parallel, then you can find where they intersect by solving a system of simultaneous equations which in this case you can do by inverting a 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using vectors

```js
// calculating A, B, C, you can ignore that part
const a = 1
const h = a * Math.sqrt(3) / 2
const R =  2 / 3 * h
const A = { x: 0, y: R }
const B = { x: -a / 2, y: h / 3 }
const C = { x: a / 2, y: h / 3 }

console.log('A=', A, 'B=', B, 'C=', C)

// number of points on each side
const parts = 3
const sides = [[A, B], [B, C], [C, A]]
const points = []
for (const [f, s] of sides) {
  // for each side calculate a vector (e.g. A -> B)
  const v = { x: s.x - f.x, y: s.y - f.y }
  for (let i = 1; i <= parts; i += 1) {
    // calculate position of each points
    // e.g. (A + ABvector * 1/3)
    const p = { x: f.x + v.x / parts * i, y: f.y + v.y / parts / i }
    points.push(p)
  }
}
console.log('points=', points)
```